# Can this ORDER BY on a CASE clause be made faster?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I'm selecting results from a table of ~350 million records, and it's running extremely slowly - around 10 minutes.  The culprit seems to be the **ORDER BY**, as if I remove it the query only takes a moment.  Here's the gist:

```
SELECT TOP 100
    (columns snipped)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN (e2.ID IS NULL) THEN
            CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END AS RecordExists,
        (columns snipped)
    FROM dbo.Files AS e1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Records AS e2 ON e1.FID = e2.FID
)  AS p1
ORDER BY p1.RecordExists
```

Basically, I'm ordering the results by whether *Files* have a corresponding *Record*, as those without need to be handled first.  I could run two queries with **WHERE** clauses, but I'd rather do it in a single query if possible.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: When you remove the `ORDER BY` are you also removing the `TOP 100`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this form a try

```
SELECT TOP(100) *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(100)
        0 AS RecordExists
        --,(columns snipped)
    FROM dbo.Files AS e1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Records e2 WHERE e1.FID = e2.FID)
    ORDER BY SecondaryOrderColumn
) X
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(100)
        1 AS RecordExists
        --,(columns snipped)
    FROM dbo.Files AS e1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Records AS e2 ON e1.FID = e2.FID
    ORDER BY SecondaryOrderColumn
) X
ORDER BY SecondaryOrderColumn
```

Key indexes:
Records (FID)
Files (FID, SecondaryOrdercolumn)

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate issue is that the use of CASE in the sub-query introduces an ORDER BY over something that is *not* being used in a [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) manner. Thus the *entire* intermediate result-set must first be ordered to find the TOP 100 - this is all 350+ million records!<sup>2</sup>

In this particular case, moving the CASE to the outside SELECT and use a DESC ordering (to put NULL values, which means "0" in the current RecordExists, first) should do the trick<sup>1</sup>. It's not a generic approach, though .. but the ordering should be much, much faster *iff* Files.ID is indexed. (If the query is still slow, consult the query plan to find out why ORDER BY is *not* using an index.)

Another alternative might be to include a *persisted computed* column for RecordExists (that is also indexed) that can be used as an index in the ORDER BY.

Once again, **the idea is that the ORDER BY works over something [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)**, which only requires reading sequentially inside the index (up to the desired number of records to match the outside limit) and *not* ordering 350+ million records on-the-fly :)

SQL Server is then able to push this ordering (and limit) *down* into the sub-query, instead of waiting for the intermediate result-set of the sub-query to come *up*. Look at the query plan differences based on *what* is being ordered.

---

<sup>1</sup> Example:

```
SELECT TOP 100
    -- If needed
    CASE WHEN (p1.ID IS NULL) THEN
        CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END AS RecordExists,
    (columns snipped)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (columns snipped)
    FROM dbo.Files AS e1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Records AS e2 ON e1.FID = e2.FID
)  AS p1
-- Hopefully ID is indexed, DESC makes NULLs (!RecordExists) go first
ORDER BY p1.ID DESC
```

---

<sup>2</sup> Actually, it seems like it could *hypothetically* just stop after the first 100 0's without a full-sort .. at least under some extreme query planner optimization *under a closed function range*, but that depends on *when* the 0's are encountered in the intermediate result set (in the first few thousand or not until the hundreds of millions or never?). I *highly doubt* SQL Server accounts for this extreme case anyway; that is, don't count on this still *non-sargable* behavior.

Comment: This is a great answer.  The rest of the story on my question is that I'm using LINQ to construct these queries, and I'm not able to work out how to come up with your approach in LINQ, whereas Richard's was straightforward.  Very educational, though - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason it is much slower is because it is really a very different query without the order by clause.

With the order by clause:
Find all matching records out of the entire 350 million rows.  Then sort them.

Without the order by clause:
Find the first 100 matching records.  Stop.

Comment: It's not this simple. I believe that once the CASE is introduced the ability to use an index is thrown out .. because if it *could* employ an ORDER BY over an index, then it would be quick and could stop over the first 100 (read sequentially from index end).

Comment: Possibly, if you assume the bottleneck is the sort.  But it is also possible that the bottleneck is having to read 350 million rows.  I think @MartinSmith is asking the right question in the question comments.

Comment: @pst: the use of **any** computed value ( such as a `case` expression) prohibits the optimizer from indices involving the base value of such expressions.

Comment: @NicholasCarey .. but this answer doesn't address the case of there ORDER BY over an index.

Answer (score 0):

Q: If you say the only difference is "with/outout" the "order by", then could you somehow move the "top 100" into the *inner* select?

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT
    (columns snipped)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100
        CASE WHEN (e2.ID IS NULL) THEN
            CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END AS RecordExists,
        (columns snipped)
    FROM dbo.Files AS e1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Records AS e2 ON e1.FID = e2.FID
)  AS p1
ORDER BY p1.RecordExists
```

Comment: Selecting the top 100 prior to ordering changes the meaning of query, though.  I want as many *RecordExists = 0* as I can get before going into the 1s (up to 100).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, `null` values collate lower than any value in the domain. Given these two tables:

```
create table dbo.foo
(
  id   int         not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  name varchar(32) not null unique nonclustered ,
)

insert dbo.foo ( name ) values ( 'alpha' )
insert dbo.foo ( name ) values ( 'bravo' )
insert dbo.foo ( name ) values ( 'charlie' )
insert dbo.foo ( name ) values ( 'delta' )
insert dbo.foo ( name ) values ( 'echo' )
insert dbo.foo ( name ) values ( 'foxtrot' )
go

create table dbo.bar
(
  id     int         not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  foo_id int             null foreign key references dbo.foo(id) ,
  name   varchar(32) not null unique nonclustered ,
)
go
insert dbo.bar( foo_id , name ) values( 1 , 'golf' )
insert dbo.bar( foo_id , name ) values( 5 , 'hotel' )
insert dbo.bar( foo_id , name ) values( 3 , 'india' )
insert dbo.bar( foo_id , name ) values( 5 , 'juliet' )
insert dbo.bar( foo_id , name ) values( 6 , 'kilo' )
go
```

The query

```
select *
from      dbo.foo foo
left join dbo.bar bar on bar.foo_id = foo.id
order by bar.foo_id, foo.id
```

yields the following result set:

```
id name    id   foo_id name
-- ------- ---- ------ -------
2  bravo   NULL NULL   NULL
4  delta   NULL NULL   NULL
1  alpha   1    1      golf
3  charlie 3    3      india
5  echo    2    5      hotel
5  echo    4    5      juliet
6  foxtrot 5    6      kilo

(7 row(s) affected)
```

This *should* allow the query optimizer to use a suitable index (if such exists); however, it does *not* guarantee than any such index would be used.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT TOP 100
    (columns snipped)
FROM dbo.Files AS e1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Records AS e2 ON e1.FID = e2.FID
ORDER BY e2.ID ASC
```

This should give you where e2.ID is null first. Also, make sure Records.ID is indexed. This should give you the ordering you were wanting.